# Ubuntu 17.10 freezes after suspend

Tags: suspend, ubuntu-gnome

After i suspend Ubuntu 17.10 , when I try to power on (get out from the suspend state) it shows the login screen then crashes after few seconds.

It's the same thing with each suspend.

Please tell me in the comments which informations I should provide to solve this problem.

## Update

I don't know if this is important or not, but in each session, when I use
the command `journalctl -p crit`, the outputs is this :

> gnome-session-binary[964]: CRITICAL: Unable to create a DBus proxy for GnomeScreensaver: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.ScreenSaver: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.gnome.ScreenSaver exited with status 1

Comment: facing on my 16.04 too

Comment: @Abdulla Nillam are you using gnome shell or unity ??

Comment: using unity on ubuntu

Comment: Crashing means... that you are stuck in a loop?

Comment: it doesn't look like a loop, the login screen just freezes

Comment: Have you tried changing to GDM?

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10 uses gdm by default I guess

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot... So changing to lightdm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was causing the problem in my situation.

Before, I changed the default i/o scheduler from `cfq` to `bfq` using this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375600/how-to-enable-and-use-the-bfq-scheduler/376136#376136 .

Now I switched back to `cfq`, and it is working great for now (I tried to suspend multiples times, no crash).

I hope this answer helps someone.

Comment: I'm not sure if this got broken after the kernel upgrade or some module, and my upgraded 17.10 us using `cfq` :(